# Создание динамических блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yandex-maps-api

Есть json такой структуры

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Всеволожский",
    "polygonpoints": "[30.5225209,59.9170186],[30.522556255339,59.917003955339],[30.5225709,59.9169686],[30.522556255339,59.916933244661],[30.5225209,59.9169186],[30.522485544661,59.916933244661],[30.5224709,59.9169686],[30.522485544661,59.917003955339]"


}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Выборгский",
    "polygonpoints": "[30.070784,60.0962496],[30.0742072,60.0939662],[30.0768868,60.0904474],[30.0832814,60.0881452],[30.0871855,60.0868775],[30.08843,60.0865811],[30.0945407,60.0853186],[30.102799,60.0808527],[30.1042255,60.0795927],[30.1121051,60.0726668],[30.1160174,60.0718794],[30.1191347,60.070006]"

    }]
```

Добавляю с помощью этих координат, построить полигоны на карте

```
ymaps.ready(init);

    function init(){
        var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [30.33,59.93],
            zoom: 11,
            behaviors: ['default', 'scrollZoom'],
            controls: ['mapTools']
        });

    $.ajax({
  url: 'district.js',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    let length = data.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      raions_polygonpoints.push(data[i].name);
      polygonpoints.push(data[i].polygonpoints);

    }
    var myPolygon = [];
    polygonpoints.forEach(function(item, i) {
      console.log(i + ": " + item);

      /*----Формирование границ-------*/
      myPolygon[i] = new ymaps.Polygon([

        [item]

      ], {

        hintContent: "Многоугольник"
      }, {

        fillColor: '#00FF0088',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
      });


      map.geoObjects.add(myPolygon[i]);


    });
  }
});

}
```

Ошибок не выдает, предполагаю проблема `[item]` Если статично задавать ,все отрисовывает.

Comment: попробуй сделать `JSON.parse('[' + item + ']')` перед тем, как передать его в `ymaps.Polygon`

Comment: @vihtor , спасибо, это помогло.